# Error/Output streams with current java process

Tags: java, process, stream

I know to use `ErrorStream` or `OutputStream` you do the following

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime ().exec ("the command you want to execute");
OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream ();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream ();
```

What if I don't want to start a new process, I want to get the `ErrorStream` & `OutputStream` of the current application I am working on. (The current process).

How to get it ?

Comment: Use `System.out` and `System.error`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use `System.out` and `System.err`.